# In opencv imshow() function does not open the new window and display the image in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

```
    import cv2
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    status , photo = cap.read()
    cv2.imwrite('Surendar.png',photo)
    cap.release()  
    cv2.imshow('image', photo) 
    cv2.waitKey(5000) 
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I interpreted this code in my jupyter notebook. It just complies but **does not show the new window of picture**.

Comment: I presume the jupyter server is not running on the local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `cv2.waitKey(5000)` to `cv2.waitKey(0)` so the window will stay up until the user closes it. It looks like the window was waiting for 5000 milliseconds before it would destroy the window.

**EDIT**

Instead of using cv2 to display your image, try using matplot instead

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
status , photo = cap.read()
cv2.imwrite('Surendar.png',photo)
cap.release()  
plt.imshow(photo)
plt.show()
```

Comment: even if i change it to  `cv2.waitKey(0)` it still **does not** open the new window to display the image